# PHP 5.3 ZipArchive issue

Tags: php

I have 5 accounts hosted at the same hosting plan, to each account I load my PHP CMS, hand made.

I Upload a `CMS.zip` and an `UnZip.php` file, the entire system works fine as long as the server is configured to work with PHP 5.2.

Recently I encountered an issue with my latest account configured as PHP 5.3, the CMS code is the same, But does not work, after a long and exhausting conversation with the support, they resolved that my code is set to extract only with PHP 5.2 not with 5.3.

I use a standard PHP `ZipArchive` Class to handle extractions, which is why I found this weird, in any case  I searched for a proper handle to un zip with PHP 5.3 but with no luck.

Can someone please tell me how this code, attached to this question, should be written? 
P.s 
the support mentioned that the ZipArchive class is in fact active on the server.

Here is my code:

```
   $DIR_NAME = getcwd();

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open('ZipTest.zip') === TRUE) {
        $zip->extractTo($DIR_NAME);
        $zip->close();

        if(file_exists('editor.php')){
            echo '<u style="color:Green;">File Found ::   Extraction Complete !!</u><br>';
            echo $DIR_NAME.' : 
        <b style="color:orange;">ZipTest.zip Activated Seccessfully!</b> <a href="dir_inventory.php">Load CMS</a><br>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<u style="color:red;"><b> ERORR </b>::   Extraction Failure !!</u><br>';

        }
    } 
    else {
        echo '<b style="color:red;">Cant Exctract ZipTest.zip file to location!</b>';
    }
```

Comment: What is the exact PHP error you are getting back? Turn error reporting on and up if you are not sure.

Comment: No error report printed, error report is active. They say this is a 5.3 error.

Comment: Code is working with 5.3. Either the zip is wrong, or directory permissions lacking and error reporting is *not* enabled. Either way too localized, we can only guess without access.

Comment: Hay, first of, thanks so much for your quick response, as for the error reporting a just ran a quick one, you were right it was sett at the top of the file wrong, which i forgot to include for this example. my error is : 
failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: @RmH so we were right and as mario says you need to open up the permissions to the web user so it can write to the directory you have specified.

Comment: Yup, look like it. Thanks Yall...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my class to work with Zip.

I have no trouble with it on PHP 5.3.8.

```
<?php

/**
 *  @author         Andrew Zavadsky <zaffaccky@gmail.com>
 *  @class          Zip
 *  @description    Class for manipulation ZIP (creating, unzipping)
 */

class Zip
{
    private $zip            = null;

    public function __construct($src)
    {
        $this->zip  = new ZipArchive();

        if (!file_exists($src))
            $r = $this->zip->open($src, ZipArchive::CREATE);
        else
            $r = $this->zip->open($src);
    }

    public function addFromString($as, $text)
    {
        $this->zip->addFromString($as, $text);

        return $this;
    }

    public function addFile($as, $src = null)
    {
        if ($src && file_exists($src))
            $this->zip->addFile($src, $as);
        else
            $this->zip->addFromString($as, '');

        return $this;
    }

    public function unzip($to, array $files = array())
    {
        if (!file_exists($to))
            mkdir($to);

        if (!is_writable($to) || !is_dir($to))
            throw new Exception(sprintf('Target directory %s is not directory or not for writing', $to));

        if (count($files))
            $this->zip->extractTo($to, $files);
        else
            $this->zip->extractTo($to);

        $this->zip->close();

        return $this;
    }

    public function addFolder($as, $src = null)
    {
        $as = trim($as, '\\/');

        $this->zip->addEmptyDir($as);

        if ($src && file_exists($src) && is_dir($src))
            $this->addFiles($src, $as);

        return $this;
    }

    private function addFiles($from, $to = '', $recursive = true)
    {
        $from   = rtrim($from, '\\/');
        $to     = trim($to, '\\/');

        if (!is_dir($from))
            throw new Exception(sprintf('Can\'t add files from folder %s', $from));
        else
            $this->zip->addEmptyDir($to);


        foreach (scandir($from) as $i => $f)
        {
            if ($i <= 1)
                continue;

            if (is_dir($file = $from . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $f) && $recursive)
                $this->addFiles($file, $to . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $f, $recursive);
            else
                $this->addFile($to ? $to . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $f : $f, $file);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Try it, you need $zip->unzip($to, $options);

Comment: Hi answered,
Thanks for the class, to save time, by : $zip->unzip($to, $options);
You mean : $zip->unzip($Dir, $Zip); ??

Comment: $zip = new Zip(PATH_TO_YOUR_ZIP_ARCHIVE); $zip->unzip(WHERE); Second argument is not required, it's just a mask, if you want to extract not all files, then there you specify what files to extract. If you need unzip into same dir, then $zip->unzip('.');

Comment: also, you need to chmod 777 DIRNAME, where you want to allocate files from archive